# Running exactly same commands multiple times in a simple/efficient way

Tags: r

I am merging two datasets in R by a string variable which is a bit messy (webscrapted data on institutional affiliations of scientific authors onto Web of Science data). Because the id-variable is messy I do a lot of rounds of manipulating the id-variable, merging, manipulting the id-variable, merging and so on.

The way I manipulate is different from round to round, but the merging part is the same every time:

```
b_suc <- merged_b[is.na(merged_b$cwts_organization_id)==F, ]
b_suc <- subset(b_suc, select = c(contribs, cwts_organization_id))
merged <- merge(merged, b_suc, by="contribs", all.x=T)
merged$cwts_organization_id.x <- 
  ifelse(is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id.x)==T & is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id.y)==F,
         merged$cwts_organization_id.y,
         merged$cwts_organization_id.x)
merged <- rename(merged, cwts_organization_id = cwts_organization_id.x)
merged <- subset(merged, select = -c(cwts_organization_id.y))

succes <- c(succes, sum(is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id)==F))
unsuc <- merged[is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id)==T, ]
unsuc <- subset(unsuc, select = -c(cwts_organization_id, short_name, city, id))
```

This is a lot of code (which is exactly the same every time) so it would be nice to do it in a shorter way. One way is to define a function of the code. This does not work with `<-` because that only defines the variables in the functions environment, and I need them be in the global environment, so I use `<<-` instead:

```
append_end <- function(){
  b_suc <<- merged_b[is.na(merged_b$cwts_organization_id)==F, ]
  b_suc <<- subset(b_suc, select = c(contribs, cwts_organization_id))
  merged <<- merge(merged, b_suc, by="contribs", all.x=T)
  merged$cwts_organization_id.x <<- 
    ifelse(is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id.x)==T & is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id.y)==F,
           merged$cwts_organization_id.y,
           merged$cwts_organization_id.x)
  merged <<- rename(merged, cwts_organization_id = cwts_organization_id.x)
  merged <<- subset(merged, select = -c(cwts_organization_id.y))
  
  succes <<- c(succes, sum(is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id)==F))
  unsuc <<- merged[is.na(merged$cwts_organization_id)==T, ]
  unsuc <<- subset(unsuc, select = -c(cwts_organization_id, short_name, city))
}
```

Now I can just call `append_end()` after each round of manipulation which is much easier.

To my understanding, however, using `<<-` is considered bad coding practice by some, so I was wondering if there was a different/better way of being able to run my several code lines in a single line, than the one I use here?
Because of my data and the tasks I need to do, looping over the different ways of manipulating the id-variable is not really an option.

Comment: Put your data structures in a list, pass that list as a parameter to the function and have the function return the updated list.